# Text won't wrap around image

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a block of text wrap around an image and it refuses to do so. Tried using `float` which seemed to work previously but not now. I'm not amazing in CSS or HTML so editing it hasn't worked too well as of yet.

I've put borders around it to show what the issue is:

[image]

I'm trying to make that block of text wrap around the image but it won't budge.

If anybody could be of assistance I'd appreciate it greatly. My current code so far is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="teamimg_1"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Student Letting</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum 200 words ... </p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.teamimg_1 {
  border: solid black 2px;
  float: left;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
```

If I've not shown enough of the coding please let me know - I'm going to keep at it, I've got every book open in front of me trying to figure this out!

Comment: Where is the image in your HTML?

Comment: why not use CSS `top, left, bottom and right` properties instead of float? Add a `z-index` and you should be able to do it!

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/378/?

Comment: @Sampson - sorry, forgot to mention, I put it in my CSS not sure if that's a problem or not.

Comment: @lb1021 The text can't float around an object that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like - from your comment above - the image of the individual is actually part of the background of the larger element. I would strongly encourage you to avoid this approach, and instead use a real image in the document itself. Not only is this more structurally sound and semantically proper, it also allows you to simply float the media content, and achieve your desired result:

```html
<section>
    <figure>
        <image alt="Sample Photo" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/"/>
    </figure>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor et sit</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Integer purus leo...</p>
</section>
```

And then simply float the figure:

```css
figure {
    float: left;
}
```

Results: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/quh1502x/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
```

to your image

the absolute position will remove margins. you will have to adjust the margins after applying this